# Python Selenium Chrome не правильное поведение браузера

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Пишу парсер. Имеется пагинация, где необходимо пройтись по всем страницам и собрать url.
 Переход осуществляется нажатием на кнопку далее (url сайта не меняется, скорее всего данные подгружаются c ajax).

Проблема в том, что после просмотра, оказалось что имеются повторы, которые не должны быть.

Посмотрев посещенные сайты и смотря в браузер в данный момент, я увидел, что хоть переключение между страницами пагинации срабатывало, но контент не менялся.

Я поставил все возможные ожидания, но проблему это не спасло.

Такое поведение только в Chrome, в Firefox с этим все нормально.

Код:

```
def init_driver():
    ff = "../install/chromedriver.exe"
    chrome_option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()


    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ff, options=chrome_option)
    except SessionNotCreatedException:
        print("Ошибка инициализации браузера. Скорее всего у вас не установлен браузер. Пожалуйста обратитесь к разработчику парсера")

    return driver

def close_pop_up_window(driver):
    blocks = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
        "div.b-popup.js-popup > div > div.b-popup__header.js-popup__header > div")
    for block in blocks:
        try:
            block.click()
            print("Нижнее окно закрыли")

            break
        except:
            continue
    time.sleep(1)





def parse_list_develops(driver):
    urls_develop = []
    driver.get("https://www.hurriyetemlak.com/projeler/developers")
    print("Ожидание 6 секунд. Обход защиты")
    time.sleep(6)

    while True:
        time.sleep(2)

        #Ищем ссылки на проекты:
        a_list_develop = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.b-developer__logo-wrap > a")
        for a in a_list_develop:
            href = a.get_attribute("href")
            print("Ссылка на проект", href)
            urls_develop.append(href)

        #Блок пагинации
        try:
            pagination_block = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.b-pagination__item.b-pagination__item--next.js-pagination-next")))
            pagination_block.click()
            print("Перешли на следующую страницу")
        except Exception as e:
            try:
                print("Проверка наличия всплываюшего окна")
                button_close = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.b-button.b-button--full.b-button--confirm")
                time.sleep(2)
                button_close.click()
                time.sleep(2)
                print("Окно закрыли")
                pagination_block = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.b-pagination__item.b-pagination__item--next.js-pagination-next")))
                pagination_block.click()
                print("Нажатие на pagination снова")
            except Exception as e:
                print("Pagination не найдены. Конец перехода между страницами", e)
                break

    return urls_develop, driver


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    driver = init_driver()
    urls, driver = parse_list_develops(driver)
    print("Количество ссылок:", len(urls))
    urls = list(set(urls))

    print("Количество ссылок обновленных:",len(urls))
```

Comment: Уважаемый, что ж Вы мечетесь между Firefox и Chrome? :) То у вас один глючит, то другой. Для данного вопроса советую последить за тем, все ли Network запросы отрабатываются успешно. Посмотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53123641/9921853) как это можно сделать

Comment: @SergeyNudnov был бы стабильный вариант, не использовал бы разные.